# Solr indexing showing error

Tags: csv, solr, rhel7

I have installed solr 6.4 in RHEL 7 . I have created a core named PLI . I am trying to import and index a csv file using the command:

```
    curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/PLI/update?commit=true' --data-binary @tbl_PLI_stripped.csv -H 'Content-type:application/csv'
```

But is shows the following error:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">55</int></lst><lst name="error"><lst name="metadata"><str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str><str name="root-error-class">java.lang.NumberFormatException</str></lst><str name="msg">ERROR: [doc=02c020ee-fccc-455e-a687-278bfbc1c839] Error adding field 'StreetNo'='13/50' msg=For input string: "13/50"</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
```

I have filed in csv file "StreetNo".
I have added my schema in manged-schmea which is like :

```
<field name="LotPlan" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="Address" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>   
<field name="StreetSuburb" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="StreetNo" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="House_No" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
```

I am not able to resolve the issue. The same csv file in the same version of Solr in Windows, I am able to import and index.

Answer (score 0):

your StreetNo is not picking up the "string" type. If you want to set up the field types yourself, you must move from the managed schema to the classic one.

Look at [this doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+Factory+Definition+in+SolrConfig), where is says 'Switching from Managed Schema to Manually Edited schema.xml' and then you should be able to use your custom defined field.

Answer (score 0):

What's the file format? Have you tried opening the file in vi and using :set ff=unix and saving?

You'll find more detail in the solr logs on on the solr admin UI->logging.